# image placement in google maps bubble

Tags: php, javascript, image, google-maps

Im trying to put a picture on a Google maps popup balloon and when i try to place the image it ends up down towards the bottom right corner. I would like it to be a the very top under the title. I have provided the code and an image to help. [image: This is where I want to logo]

```
        <?php


    error_reporting(1);
    $a = array(
        "EAFS"=>"Andras Field"
    );
    $f = file_get_contents("http://virtual-aviation.org/whazzup/whazzup.txt");
    if ($f) {
        $f = substr($f,strpos($f,"!CLIENTS")+10);
        $f = substr($f,0,strpos($f,"!SERVERS")-1);
        $lines = explode("\n",$f);

         if (count($lines)) {
            foreach ($lines as $l) {
                $e = array_map("htmlspecialchars",explode(":",$l));
                //Begin Airline List
                //FAA ident only eg AAH = Aloha
                if (strpos($e[0],'AAH') !==false){
                $cs='<img style="float:top" src="http://www.virtual-aviation.org/main/map/alogos/aah.png"/>';}
                if (strpos($e[0],'AAL') !==false){
                $cs='<img src="http://www.virtual-aviation.org/main/map/alogos/aal.png"/>';}
                //End Airline Listing
                if (substr($e[0],0,8) == "!SERVERS") {
                    $o = array("error"=>"Issue with flight data. Try again later!");
                    break;
                }

                if ($e[3] == "ATC") {
                    $o["markers"][] = array(
                        "type"=>"atc",
                        "callsign"=>$e[0],
                        "ang"=>"",
                        "pos"=>array(
                            "x"=>$e[5],
                            "y"=>$e[6]
                        ),
                        "list"=>$e[0],
                        "desc"=>    '<b>Air Traffic Controller</b>'.
                                        '<br />Callsign: '.$e[0].
                                        '<br />Username: '.$e[1]

                    );
                } else {

                    $o["markers"][] = array(
                        "type"=>"pilot",
                        "callsign"=>$e[0],
                        "ang"=>round($e[45],-1)%360,
                        "pos"=>array(
                            "x"=>$e[5],
                            "y"=>$e[6]
                        ),
                        "list"=>$e[0],
                        "desc"=>    '<b>Pilot</b>'.                                      
 '<p>'.$cs.'</p>'.
                                        '<br />Callsign: '.$e[0].
                                        '<br />Username: '.$e[1].
                                        '<br />Heading: '.$e[45].
                                        '<br />Altitude: '.(($e[7])?$e[7].' Ft':"On Ground").
                                        '<br />Ground Speed: '.$e[8].' Knots'.
                                        '<br />Aircraft: '.$e[9].
                                        '<br />Destination Airport: '.(($e[13])?$e[13].(($a[$e[13]])?" (".$a[$e[13]].")":""):"Not filled").
                                        '<br />Departure Airport: '.(($e[11])?$e[11].(($a[$e[11]])?" (".$a[$e[11]].")":""):"Not filled").
                                        '<br />Flight Route: '.(($e[30])?$e[30]:"Not filled")
                    );
                }
            }
        } else {
            $o = array("error"=>"There are no connected clients.");
        }
    } else {
        $o = array("error"=>"Failed to retrieve flight data2. Try again later!");
    }

    echo json_encode($o);
    ?>
```

Here is the contents of the javascript file

```
function MapLabel(childmarker, label, map) {
    this.childmarker = childmarker;
    this.label = label;

    this.div = null;
    this.setMap(map);
}
function initializeLabels() {
    MapLabel.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

    MapLabel.prototype.onAdd = function() {
        var div = document.createElement("div");

        div.style.background = "#FFF";
        div.style.border = "1px solid #000";
        div.style.position = "absolute";
        div.style.display = "none";
        div.style.fontSize = "x-small";
        div.style.padding = "2px";
        div.innerHTML = this.label;

        this.div = div;

        var panes = this.getPanes();
        panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
    }
    MapLabel.prototype.draw = function() {
        var p = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.childmarker.position);

        this.div.style.left = p.x + 15 + 'px';
        this.div.style.top = p.y - 40 + 'px';
        this.div.style.display = "block";
    }
    MapLabel.prototype.onRemove = function() {
        this.div.parentNode.removeChild(this.div);
        this.div = null;
    }
}
function initialize() {
    mapObj = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"), {
        zoom: 2,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.651,10.7655),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    });

    $.getJSON("markers.php",function(data){
        if (data == null) {
            $("#notice").html("Failed to load markers file.");
        } else if (data.error) {
            $("#notice").html(data.error);
        } else {
            $.each(data.markers, function(k, marker) {
            //for (var i=0; i<data.markers.length; i++) {
                //var marker = data.markers[i];
                var mark = new google.maps.Marker({
                    "position": new google.maps.LatLng(marker.pos.x,marker.pos.y),
                    "map": mapObj,
                    "icon": "markers/"+marker.type+marker.ang+".png"
                });
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        "content": marker.desc
                });
                var label = new MapLabel(mark, marker.callsign, mapObj);

                google.maps.event.addListener(mark, "click", function() {
                    if (infowindow.isopen) {
                        infowindow.close();
                        infowindow.isopen = false;
                    } else {
                        infowindow.open(mapObj,mark);
                        infowindow.isopen = true;
                    }
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, "closeclick", function() {
                    infowindow.isopen = false;
                });

                $("<div />").html(marker.list).click(function() {
                    mapObj.panTo(mark.position);
                }).appendTo($("#clients").children("#"+marker.type));
            //}
            });
            $("#notice").css({"width": "90%", "font-weight": "bold"}).html("<marquee>Click on aircraft for flight information | Click on Andras Field to view aircrafts in the area</marquee>");
        }
        $("img").hide();
    });
}

$(function() {
    initializeLabels();
    initialize();
});
```

and the client side code

```
                                  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Map</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
<script type="php" src="markers.php"></script>
<style type="text/css">
body,html,#mapDiv {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial;
    font-size: small;
}
a {
    color: #F00;
}
img,#notice {
    position: absolute;
    right: 3px;
    bottom: 15px;
    font-size: x-small;
    color: #FFF;
}
#clients {
    position: absolute;
    left: 2px;
    bottom: 2px;
    padding: 4px;
    background: #FFF;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
}
#clients div {
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mapDiv"></div>
    <img src="loading.gif" />
    <div id="notice"></div>
    <div id="clients">
        <div id="atc">
            <b>ATCs</b>
        </div>
        <div id="pilot">
            <b>Pilots</b>
        </div>
        <br /><a href="./">Refresh Map!</a>
        <br /><a href="javascript:;" onclick="mapObj.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(47.645,10.7555)); mapObj.setZoom(14)">Andras Field</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: exact duplicate of [Image is not appearing where I intended in the popup ballon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9372592/image-is-not-appearing-where-i-intended-in-the-popup-ballon)

Comment: Is it just the AAH logo that messes up, or is it the AAL as well? I'm seeing a `float:top` on the AAH, but that value for the `float` property is not valid. If both are messing up though, then that can't be the (only) problem.

Comment: All the logos that i have placed there have messed up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see the problem. In your CSS, you have a style:

```
img,#notice {
    position: absolute;
    right: 3px;
    bottom: 15px;
    font-size: x-small;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

This will be applied to all images on the page, which includes your logo images. It seems that that selector is supposed to apply to the loader, so try using a class or ID instead.